# CFBundleShortVersionString returns an outdated value

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, plist

in one of my apps I need to read app version to validate it against some conditions. To read it I execute this code

```swift
var version: String {
    return Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: versionKey) as! String
}
```

I added this functionality in version `2.2.0`. It was working good in my debug builds, but when submitted to App Store it started to fail. To investigate it I added code that sends a non-fatal issue to Crashlytics with version in the message (added in `2.2.1`).
And now there's a funny part - in Crashlytics logs I can see that some non-fatals are from version `2.2.1` with message `"Version: 2.2.1"`, and some other ones are from version `2.0.0` with message `"Version: 2.0.0"`. So app version `2.2.1` reads its version as `2.0.0`.

Have any of you experienced such thing? Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: Under what version does crashlytics show these 2.0.0 events?

Comment: Under `2.0.0`. Crashlytics reads the same version as me.